# php - turn a list of inputs into a json string

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax, input

I have a list of inputs. The number of slots depends of a "foreach" that decodes a json string and loop the values like this:

```
    slot-1 : <input id="slot-1" type="texte" value="#FFFF00"><br>
    slot-2 : <input id="slot-2" type="texte" value="#9ACD32"><br>
    slot-3 : <input id="slot-3" type="texte" value="#008000"><br>
    slot-4 : <input id="slot-4" type="texte" value="#0d98ba"><br>
    slot-5 : <input id="slot-5" type="texte" value="#0000ff"><br>
    slot-6 : <input id="slot-6" type="texte" value="#8a2be2"><br>
    ....
    ...
    ..
    .
```

I try to find the best method to json_encode after changing the values in order to get this pattern : {"input's id":"input's value",}

```
{"slot-1":"#FFFF00","slot-2":"#9ACD32","slot-3":"#008000","slot-4":"#0d98ba","slot-5":"#0000ff"}
```

And send it with a jQuery ajax query like this

```
$(document).on('click', '#actualiser', function(){
        var couleurs = '<?php echo $slots; ?>';
        $.ajax({
            url:"/url.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                slots:slots
                },
            success:function(data)
            {   
                console.log("ok");
            }
        })
    });
```

I have done test but I only get very messy process.. Any idea to achieve that "clean" ?

Comment: what is `<?php echo $slots; ?>`   ?

Comment: OP has probably got the Javascript in a <script> tag in their PHP file, allowing them to pass in PHP variables. I assume $slots is serialised form data, based on where it is being passed into the function.

Comment: @delboy1978uk that's the string I want to create to send it to a database. I could be wrong. As I said This issue make me do messy codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***1.You need to get all input data and then send to PHP***

```js
$(document).on('click', '#actualiser', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var couleurs =[];
  $('#actualiser-form input').each(function(){
    var item = {};
    item[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
    couleurs.push(item);
  });
  
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(couleurs);
  console.log(jsonString);
  $.ajax({
    url:"/url.php",
    method:"POST",
    data: jsonString,
    success:function(data)
    {   
      console.log("ok");
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="actualiser-form">
  slot-1 : <input id="slot-1" type="text" value="#FFFF00"><br>
  slot-2 : <input id="slot-2" type="text" value="#9ACD32"><br>
  slot-3 : <input id="slot-3" type="text" value="#008000"><br>
  slot-4 : <input id="slot-4" type="text" value="#0d98ba"><br>
  slot-5 : <input id="slot-5" type="text" value="#0000ff"><br>
  slot-6 : <input id="slot-6" type="text" value="#8a2be2"><br>
  
  <input type="submit" id="actualiser" name="submit" value ="Click me" />
</form>
```

***2.At PHP end check you are getting data or not***

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
  echo"<pre/>";print_r($_POST); // check and then do next code accordingly
}
```

Comment: that works very well. Is there a way to submit a pattern like this {"slot-1":"#FFFF00","slot-2":"#9ACD32"....} instead of [{"slot-1":"#FFFF00"},{"slot-2":"#9ACD32"}....]

Comment: that pattern only going to be submitted. check console of my code snippet

Comment: I see... Anyway thanks for your answer. Works very well

Comment: @Morse  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#actualiser', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var couleurs = $('#actualiser-form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url:"/url.php",
            method:"POST",
            data: couleurs,
            success:function(data)
            {   
                console.log("ok");
            }
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="actualiser-form">
  slot-1 : <input name="slot-1" type="texte" value="#FFFF00"><br>
  slot-2 : <input name="slot-2" type="texte" value="#9ACD32"><br>
  slot-3 : <input name="slot-3" type="texte" value="#008000"><br>
  slot-4 : <input name="slot-4" type="texte" value="#0d98ba"><br>
  slot-5 : <input name="slot-5" type="texte" value="#0000ff"><br>
  slot-6 : <input name="slot-6" type="texte" value="#8a2be2"><br>
  
  <button type="submit" id="actualiser">Click me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I was finishing my post with the actual same code, except I would suggest to put the type of the button to type="button" to avoid submitting

Comment: Yes that would work too. Not sure there is a 'right' approach with those two choices (e.preventDefault() or type="button").

Comment: @AlexMulchinock I really like your solution... The only change I had to do is to change "id" to "name". serialize() works with names =). If you edit your post, I would be more than happy to tick it =)

Comment: Actually you can use any valid CSS selector for the form - https://api.jquery.com/serialize/
Edit: My apologies, I misread your comment - I think you meant the form fields needed names? I've added this. :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP happens before the html is sent to the browser. So you are posting whatever you set that php var as, meaning no changes will be picked up.

Instead, just grab the inputs with `$('#whatever').val()`, and then put that into your data section

Comment: indeed. =) The problem I had is I never know how may inputs I will get.. depending of a lot of factors. So I needed to automatise a bit..